# How to Optimize mysql query the brings huge quantity of rows?

Tags: mysql, database

I really need your help. I´m doing one work from my universitiy and before I come here I read a lot of things from the documentations of mysql, searched and searched but none of this helped me in my sql query. Look I have this query:

```
SELECT a.nome, COUNT(*)
FROM publ p JOIN auth a on p.pubid = a.pubid
WHERE p.pubid IN (SELECT pubid
FROM auth
GROUP BY pubid
HAVING COUNT(*) < 3) // THIS VALUE 3 here I have to do with value 2, 4 and 5
GROUP BY a.nome      // in different querys.
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, a.nome ASC
```

I tried to put index in the where clause but I never get the results and takes to long time. What can I do to increase my query to bring me more faster the results? Thank you for the help

Comment: Your sub select *seems* wrong. `SELECT pubid
FROM auth
GROUP BY pubid
HAVING COUNT(*) < 3` makes little sense. Are you trying to use `LIMIT` to get the top 3 ?

Comment: @JacquesAmar here´s the problem, this is what our professor told us to do.  This query should return me 331.085 rows. It takes a long long long time and don´t return. What do you mean with the sub select seems wrong?                    This auth and publ are files with: 3.095.201 rows and 1.233.214 rows respectfully

Answer (score 0):

I would create these indexes and reorder the query

```
CREATE INDEX publ_pubid ON publ(pubid);
CREATE INDEX auth_pubid ON auth(pubid, nome);

SELECT a.nome, COUNT(*)
FROM (
   SELECT pubid
   FROM auth
   GROUP BY pubid
   HAVING COUNT(*) < 3
) L
LEFT JOIN publ p on L.pubid=publ.pubid
JOIN auth a on p.pubid = a.pubid
GROUP BY a.nome 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, a.nome ASC;
```